# GDI+ Text Drawing Inconsistency

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, gdi, ascii-art

I have a program that generates ASCII art from input image. The generated ASCII art is printed nicely in console. I have a function that also generates a **PNG** image with ASCII art using **GDI+**. On my laptop, the generated image looks amazing and there is no problem.

However using that **SAME** code on my other computer the generated image is skewed and doesn't look any good and i have no idea why.

Note: For majority of my program i am using *GDI+*, but for generating the image from my ASCII art i have to use *GDI* because i have to use raster font "Terminal" (which is available on any Windows machine), and GDI+ doesn't work with that font. I have a slight clue that **hfont** is somehow creating an issue because if passed 8x8px font the image looks *almost* fine.

The code of the function is:

```
VOID ASCIIFied::generate_image(VOID)
{
    if (this->decoded_art == nullptr)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to produce image from art because it's accessing nullptr reference maybe due to failed art generation or art isn't decoded yet.\nTerminating the program." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // In pixels, each letter is 8x12px + some breathing space (char_height = vertical amount of characters in art, chars_per_line = same but on horizontal axis)
    INT image_width  = this->chars_per_line * 8 + 100;
    INT image_height = this->char_height * 12 + 200;

    // Generate bitmap to draw to
    Bitmap art_output(image_width, image_height);
    Graphics g(&art_output);

    // Sets background to black
    Color color(Color::Black);
    g.Clear(color);

    // Creating proper font
    HFONT hfont = CreateFont(-8, -12, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, OEM_CHARSET, OUT_RASTER_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, PROOF_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, L"Terminal");

    // Text bounding rectangle
    RECT rc = { 50, 50, image_width,  image_height};

    HDC hdc = g.GetHDC();

    // Setting text background and foreground color to console colors along side with font
    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(210, 210, 210));

    // Apply font
    SelectObject(hdc, hfont);

    DrawTextA(hdc, this->decoded_art, -1, &rc, DT_LEFT | DT_TOP | DT_WORDBREAK);

    g.ReleaseHDC(hdc);
    DeleteObject(hfont);

    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];

    // Get Desktop path
    if (SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, NULL, 0, path) != S_OK)
    {
        cerr << "DESKTOP path not found!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    SYSTEMTIME time_s;
    GetSystemTime(&time_s);

    wstring day    = to_wstring(time_s.wDay);
    wstring month  = to_wstring(time_s.wMonth);
    wstring year   = to_wstring(time_s.wYear);
    wstring hour   = to_wstring(time_s.wHour);
    wstring minute = to_wstring(time_s.wMinute);
    wstring second = to_wstring(time_s.wSecond);

    wstring image_path(path);
    image_path += L"\\ascii_art_" + day + L"-" + month + L"-" + year + L"-" + hour + L"-" + minute + L"-" + second + L".png";

    CLSID encId = { 0x557cf406, 0x1a04, 0x11d3,{ 0x9a, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x1e, 0xf3, 0x2e } };
    art_output.Save(image_path.c_str(), &encId);

    cout << "Image saved to your desktop." << endl;
}
```

Example of a good and bad image generation respectively ->

[Good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMIhI.png)

[Bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6oBo.png)

Comment: Have you tried printing something simpler so you can see the difference easier?

Comment: Why not include a font in the program's resources, then load it? Why rely on the running PC's environment to supply what you need, when you can simply bring it yourself?

Comment: Your hardcoded pixel values are a bad smell. Maybe a DPI issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows or a "Make Text Bigger" issue https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/make-text-and-apps-bigger-c3095a80-6edd-4779-9282-623c4d721d64

Comment: I dont know what result you expect giving `-12` as width. I think it sould be `0` or more. I would also check `CreateFont` result in case it is failing. Remove `DT_WORDBREAK`. You can also try `FIXED_PITCH` instead of `DEFAULT_PITCH`. Your "good" example probably does not use Terminal font (Terminal's digit 1 has sherifs at bottom).

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yup, that's what i did the first thing i saw that suggestion. I printed 10 characters from A-G, each line consisting of 10 same characters in that span (A-G). I noticed that the problem was font scaling, check the answer because your comment lead me to solution.

Comment: @SimonMourier You're right, as my application is DPI unaware, and i've no idea how it will behave on different hardware. I should add up to my code and improve it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was quite simple and what was causing the problem was so easily overlooked.

On MSDN page for [CreateFontW()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfontw) function the first argument is **font height**, and then the second argument is **font width**.

From the provided code in my question, the bitmap width and height is calculated correctly for desired font (8x12px raster font Terminal)

```
// In pixels, each letter is 8x12px + some breathing space (char_height = vertical amount of characters in art, chars_per_line = same but on vertical axis)
INT image_width  = this->chars_per_line * 8 + 100;
INT image_height = this->char_height * 12 + 200;
```

But when actual font is created in the code, the order of arguments for font width and height is reversed when provided therefore the font mapper searches for wrong sized font which consequently won't fit when drawn in the created bitmap.
IE:

```
 HFONT hfont = CreateFont(-8, -12, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, OEM_CHARSET, OUT_RASTER_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, PROOF_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, L"Terminal");
```

The solution was to switch -8 and -12 in the function call.